# How can I use regexes to split strings by multiple delimiters, with a limit?

Tags: python

I have a rather unusual requirement for splitting. I need to use something like the limit option of `var1, var2 = string.split(delimiter, limit)`. However, string.split doesn't support multiple delimiters, which I need it to do. Therefore, I need to use re.split. How can I put a limit on re.split or otherwise acheive this splitting?

Ideally, the I would be able to input something like

```
contents = "Sentence? Sentence! Another sentence."
```

And have the two output vars be:

```
var1 = "Sentence"
var2 = "Sentence! Another sentence."
```

Comment: `re.split` takes the `maxsplit` parameter. Does it not suit you?

Comment: I don't understand the question. According to this example, you  only need to split on the question mark

Comment: `var1, var2 = contents.split('? ')`

Comment: It is not obvious that you have to `str.split` on `? ` since there could occure another delimiter before the question mark. I'll write a correct answer without using regex though

Comment: Thank you, @Marcus.Aurelianus, but that question only applies to string.split but not re.split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> re.split('[?!.]', "Sentence? Sentence! Another sentence.", maxsplit=1)
['Sentence', ' Sentence! Another sentence.']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it appears that I am just extremely foolish. My reputation is going to suffer for this one, oh well.

Comment: `help()` in the REPL is your friend.